# Can't pull dataframe head after sorting out data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, header

I'm trying to sort out some neighborhood data for a project and I'm not quite understanding what I'm doing wrong.

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M')[0]

data.head() #Works

torsort = data[ (data['Borough'] == 'Not assigned') & (data['Neighborhood'] == 'NaN') ].index

data.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)

torsort.head() #Does not work
```

Error: AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'head'

I'm not understanding what is going on and why I can't see the header of this new dataframe.

Can I get an explanation of this and how I can both understand and move forward with verifying that my filtering out of data has worked?

Thank you!

- I just realized one error, I typed over indexNames instead of torsort on my data.drop, but I'm still not pulling data.

Comment: shouldn't it be `data.head()` at the end?

Comment: As the error suggests, `torsort` is an object of 'Int64Index' type and not a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean to do something like this:

```
torsort = data[ (data['Borough'] == 'Not assigned') & (data['Neighborhood'].isnull()) ].index

data.drop(data.index[torsort])
```

Output:

```
Postal code     Borough     Neighborhood
2   M3A     North York  Parkwoods
3   M4A     North York  Victoria Village
```

etc.